# How to fix Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. "[Android/Flutter]

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, oop

i am trying to add app icon using app icon genrator for android and add all the midmapp files on resources but every times it give me such error [app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cDvh.png)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     D:\Apps\quizapp\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.quizapp:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i am trying to add app icon using app icon genrator for android and add all the midmapp files on resources but every times it give me error

Comment: Do you have icons named _ic_launcher_ inside your mipmap folders ?

Comment: no different name

Comment: Then I think you should either replace _ic_launcher_ in _AndroidManifest_ by the name of the icons, or rename icons as _ic_launcher_.